# I cannot drop a table in SQL Server 2008 r2. Also, I cannot restart the physical server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that has worked perfectly fine the past 8 months.  For some odd reason, today the query hangs and eventually times out no matter what constraint I put on it.  This is very frustrating, but extremely curious on how this can be worked around.

Query is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE xxxx.dbo.stackoverflow;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What errors are you getting when the query times out?

Comment: give to a DBA; let DBA try removing from SSMS also

Comment: Can you restart the SQL Server service? Via computer management>services>Sql Server (...), then right-click & restart.

Comment: The restart option is grayed out, so unfortunately cannot do that even though I have admin access

Comment: Well if you can't DROP the table, it must be locked somehow.

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749426/how-to-find-what-is-locking-my-tables) on StackOverflow on "how to find what is locking my tables".

Comment: thank you for the help mate!  Cheers!

Comment: Did that help you solve your issue? Question: what is the reason you need to DROP that table so often? Can you not simply TRUNCATE the table? Or does the table structure change a lot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE :  The server was restarted from the admin who was out of town.  If anyone encounters that issue in the future, I suggest either doing that, OR

type this query :

```
show full processlist;
```

after table shows, look for a query under your specific db, then get the ID from the Id column.

While the processlist is visible (***in this example, the Id will be 140***, type:

```
kill 140;
```

After removing all of the processes that have large time displays will definitely speed it up!  Good Luck!

Comment: Isn't `show full processlist` a MySQL command? Your question is tagged for SQL Server.