# How to list tables currently under delete in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

How we could find tables which are currently under delete operation or locked for delete operation?

I wanted to list such table. Is there any way to list out?

Comment: See the list of running processes and find the one executing drop table?

Comment: Have a look at this SO question. Almost answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749426/how-to-find-what-is-locking-my-tables

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code for a similar situation, Let me know if it worked fine :

```
SELECT p.spid
,convert(char(12), d.name) db_name
, program_name
, p.loginame
, convert(char(12), hostname) hostname
, cmd
, p.status
, p.blocked
, login_time
, last_batch
, p.spid
FROM      master..sysprocesses p
JOIN      master..sysdatabases d ON p.dbid =  d.dbid
WHERE     EXISTS (  SELECT 1
          FROM      master..sysprocesses p2
          WHERE     p2.blocked = p.spid )
          and cmd like '%DELETE%'
```

Comment: This wont show sessions which have executed a delete in a transaction but not yet committed if the delete isn't blocking.