# Delete Statement runs forever

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, sql-delete, sp-who2

I am facing an issue while trying to delete a set of records from a table. When I run the delete statement it ends up locking the table and hence blocking all other operations on that table. Only with NoLock hint I am able to view the result sets from the table. Did check using "SP_WHO2" as well but there is no "Blk By" SPID against any connection. Can anyone explain me what issue I am currently facing with.

```
DELETE  tbl
FROM <TableName> tbl
WHERE tbl.Condition1 = <Value> AND tbl.Condition2 = <Value> AND tbl.Condition3 = <Value>
```

Comment: How many records you have in the table?   what query you have written so far?

Comment: 1) [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/) 2) How  big is your table? 3) How do you know it is not I/O problem? 4) Do you delete all rows or some subset of table?   After we got answers for these question we may be able to help you, otherwise it will be reading tea leaves.

Comment: @RajatJaiswal First I tried deleting around a set of records (206 records) then took only 1 ID and tried deleting only one record. In both cases it is getting locked. And the statement is a simple one I am not even joining it with other tables.

Comment: then show us this simple delete statement. Also, are there any triggers on this table ? Maybe `cascade delete` is set to on for a foreign key ? If so then maybe there are triggers on that table ?

Comment: @GuidoG I have added how my delete statement looks like. There are no triggers on the table, there is no "Cascade on Delete" operation on for a foreign key.

Comment: if you turn this into a select, how many records does it returns ?

Comment: can there be concurrent transaction on this table ?First, find the default Isolation level of your database.Most probably it is because of READ COMMITTED.you should implement READ Committed Isolation Level.

Comment: Maybe someone else is locking. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749426/how-to-find-what-is-locking-my-tables?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) you can find how to check what is blocked and by whom